# React useState appends the value like string instead of incrementing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am building a very **simple counter app**, where there are **increment** and **decrement** buttons.

The count value is getting displayed according to the button clicks.

The one thing which is different here is, user can type in the value (let's say 10), then the button would respond that way,(when clicked +, then 11; when clicked the minus button then 9).

By doing so, the count value is an `input` tag itself.

[image]

I have a strange bug here :

When the app is rendered for the first time, let's say I add count value to 30, then click on `+` button, the result is `301` and not `31` means, it is appending the value at the end and not adding up.

While the above bug doesn't hold true for `-` button.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <button className="btnDe" onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev - 1)}>
        -
      </button>
      <div className="countContainer">
        <input
          type="number"
          value={count}
          onChange={(e) => setCount(e.target.value)}
          className="countInput"
        />
      </div>
      <button className="btnIn" onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CodesandBox : https://d4yz9.csb.app/

Or even the above bug doesn't hold true if I don't change the `count` value and just start it at `1`

Any little help will do :)

Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: confirm you are sending numbers to the function and not strings...  Number(count) or ParseInt(count) to explicity cast to number... + concats strings together... sounds like the issue is implicit conversion since user input is (almost always) a string

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question directly and link off-site for supporting material. `+` concatenates strings as well as performs addition. If one of your two values for addition is a string, it will coerce the other into a string and concatenate.

Comment: Yes I think I am sending numbers only, `useState(1)` at the very top

Comment: @BrianThompson Yes sure, can you take a look at at the code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/quicksell-d4yz9

Comment: `e.target.value` will always be a string. So this behavior will only happen **after** a user manually types and then increments.

Comment: @BrianThompson, Yes it worked, `e.target.value` is string. when I do `+e.target.value` it works fine. But why it works well with `-` operator ?

Comment: Because `-` doesn't perform any operation on a string, so it instead coerces the string operand to be a number.

Comment: Wow okay it is confusing how `+` doesnt perform coercing in this case

Comment: It does, it just coerces the opposite direction. Check [here for more details on type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e.target.value` is of type string.

Cast it to a number before setting:

```js
onChange={(e) => setCount(+e.target.value)}
```

Comment: @anshul mark it as accepted then, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that when you change value from input's up down arrow(browser's arrow) which will trigger onChange of input those are getting stored as string instead of number or typing numbers from input directly.

change your increment to like this (+prev) this will convert string to number

```
setCount((prev) => +prev + 1)
```

Comment: It is due to `e.target.value` stores as string

Comment: @BrianThompson i had verified that by changing number using browser's default up down arrows and it got converted in string because it was changed in onChange where e.target.value was string.

Comment: I understand what you mean now, thanks for clarifying. You may want to add that to your answer too

Answer (score 1):

cast to number to not concatenate string input :)

```
      <button className="btnIn" onClick={() => setCount((prev) => Number(prev) + 1)}>
```

Comment: This would work if you made sure you did it in every place, but the better option would be to make sure the state **always** contains a number (catch it before it changes) to protect from future changes/confusion

Comment: yes: that is significantly easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that when typing the number, it actually enters a string.
Then when adding `+1`, since `count` is now a string, it concatenates `count` and `1`.

Converting the entry to an `int` is a way to fix it :

```
onChange={(e) => setCount(parseInt(e.target.value))}
```